# Segfault when trying to add a node to front of linked list

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

Im confused why im getting a segfault in this code. gdb says the segfault occurs when I try and assign data to the list->value but I cant figure out why that would be so. Any help is appreciated!

```
 int main(){

    SingleLinkedListNode *list =  0;
    int element = 10;
    pushFront(list, element);
    //cout << list->value << endl;
}
    
SingleLinkedListNode *head = NULL;


void pushFront(SingleLinkedListNode*& list, const int data){
//checks if head points to null. if it does, 
//make head point to list and the data assigns to list->value
    if(list == NULL){
        head = list;
        list->value = data; //gdb says segfault occurs here
        return;

    }
// if head != null then make list point to the node head points to, assign 
// value to list->value and last make the head point to list node
    list->next = head;
    head = list;
    list->value = data;
    
}
```

Comment: Just think about `list->value = ...` in the `if (list == NULL)` context. What do you think you're dereferencing? Go back to basics. You're trying to hang a new node at the head of a (possibly empty) linked list. That alone means you'll need... *a new node to host the data*.  And frankly, the caller context for this is important, and inconveniently, not shown. `head` shouldn't need to be global, and in fact should be the very referenced pointer you're passing *in* to `pushFront` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is for some academic purpose, because in reality no one in their right mind would reinvent a single linked list when you could just use a [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) and be done with it (don't reinvent wheels).

You appear to be confused between trying to tie a global `head` pointer into a solution that (a) doesn't need it, and (b) doesn't want it. Worse, you don't seem to understand that a linked list data structure is a chain of *nodes*, and those nodes don't just come from  nowhere.

Your fault is coming from here:

```
if(list == NULL){ // test that list is NULL
    head = list;
    list->value = data; // list is NULL, so this dereference is bad.
    return;
```

Several things are wrong, the most troublesome being attempting to groom a global `head` pointer where none should exist. Further, hanging a new node on a linked list requires.... *a new node* (I know; it's a world gone mad).

Assuming your structure looks like this:

```
struct SingleLinkedListNode
{
    int data;
    SingleLinkedListNode *next;

    SingleLinkedListNode(int arg=0, SingleLinkedListNode *nxt = nullptr)
        : data(arg)
        , next(nxt)
    {
    }

    // squelch these
    SingleLinkedListNode(const SingleLinkedListNode&) = delete;
    SingleLinkedListNode& operator =(const SingleLinkedListNode&) = delete;
};
```

The way to push an item to the front of the passed-in list is to simply this:

```
void pushFront(SingleLinkedListNode*& lst, int data)
{
    lst = new SingleLinkedListNode(data, lst);
}
```

Note this does the following:

- Passes the data value of the new node as the first argument to the `SingleLinkedListNode` constructor.
- Passes the existing list head pointer value as the second argument to the `SingleLinkedListNode` constructor. This will be use as the `next` member value of the new node being constructed, thereby chaining the new node to the current list head.
- Finally, stores the resulting pointer-to-node as the new linked list head, which will propagate back to the caller since `lst` is a non-const reference to the caller-provided pointer.

This also means you do not need (and should not want) a global `head`. A full example of this solution is provided below.

```
#include <iostream>

struct SingleLinkedListNode
{
    int data;
    SingleLinkedListNode *next;

    SingleLinkedListNode(int arg=0, SingleLinkedListNode *nxt = nullptr)
        : data(arg)
        , next(nxt)
    {
    }

    // squelch these (Rule of 3/5/0 habit)
    SingleLinkedListNode(const SingleLinkedListNode&) = delete;
    SingleLinkedListNode& operator =(const SingleLinkedListNode&) = delete;
};

void pushFront(SingleLinkedListNode*& lst, int data)
{
    lst = new SingleLinkedListNode(data, lst);
}

void printList(const SingleLinkedListNode *lst)
{
    if (lst)
    {
        std::cout << lst->data;
        lst = lst->next;
        while (lst)
        {
            std::cout << ',' << lst->data;
            lst = lst->next;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

void freeList(SingleLinkedListNode*& lst)
{
    while (lst)
    {
        SingleLinkedListNode *tmp = lst;
        lst = lst->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SingleLinkedListNode *head = nullptr;

    for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
        pushFront(head, i);

    printList(head);
    freeList(head);
}
```

**Output**

```
10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't use your exact implementation but you definitely pointed me in the right direction and I got the function to work.